# Capture value whenever is-open (view) is changed in angular controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, accordion, angularjs-service, angular-controller

view.html

```
<uib-accordion-group heading="Header" is-open="$parent.accordionOpen" ng-click="headerClick()">
```

app.js

```
myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.accordionOpen = false;

   $scope.$watch('accordionOpen', function(){
    console.log("watch accordionOpen:" +$scope.accordionOpen);
    }, true); 
    console.log("check accordionOpen:" +$scope.accordionOpen);  

  }]);
```

'check accordionOpen:' log always prints false. I tried setting $scope.accordionOpen value to service set method but that didn't work either.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7M12F2vK0SkFnvdHg0AU?p=preview)

Upon opening the accordion, the icon is enabled and which uses ui-router to load Page1.html. In page1.html, i'm trying to check if the accordion was open/close before i display data.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is roughly equivalent to the following

```
myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.accordionOpen = false;
  console.log("check accordionOpen:" +$scope.accordionOpen);  //moved this line up

  $scope.$watch('accordionOpen', function(){
    console.log("watch accordionOpen:" +$scope.accordionOpen);
  }, true);          

}]);
```

You set `$scope.accordionOpen = false` and then immediately log the value, which is why it is always false.  I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here but your watcher should capture the value whenever it is changed.

### Update from comments

Because you are using the ui-router, your best bet is probably to listen to the $stateChangeSuccess event and capture the value there

```
myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

  $scope.accordionOpen = false;      

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
    console.log("check accordionOpen:" +$scope.accordionOpen);
    //clear list of accordion elements based on $scope.accordionOpen
  }, true);          

}]);
```

Comment: I am trying to check accordionOpen value to clear list of elements in routed page. and above doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, can you create a fiddle or plunkr that shows what you are trying to do.  I'm not clear on how you intend to accomplish that with the code you've provided.  Are you using ui-router or the built in router?

Comment: When the route changes you want to know whether the accordion was open or closed?

Comment: @Mad-D check the update.  You can listen for a stateChangeSuccess event from the ui-router and handle accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the update, but that didn't do the trick. I was hoping to capture accordionOpen value outside the function. the Page2 still loads with false value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107270/discussion-between-mad-d-and-dustin-hodges).

Comment: Sorry I can't participate with the chat.  Sitting behind a firewall that blocks it